# Can semaphores in python 2.7 work with just targetting a metod to a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multithreading

What I am trying to do is to run or pause two different functions depending on if their respective option button is active or not (the two functions execution is mutually exclusive) I tried using semaphores based on the answer given by Jay [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072608/python-is-it-possible-to-stop-or-pause-a-thread) but both threads seem to continue running. Here the code I am writing (it is inside an **__init__** block):

```
self.manual_sema = Semaphore(0)
self.auto_sema = Semaphore(0)

#Function A.

def Exec_Manual():
    while True:
        for i in range(0,5):
            if self.rbtnMan.isChecked():
                if self.rbtnAuto.isChecked():
                    self.manual_sema.acquire()
                    self.auto_sema.release()
                    break
                self._tx_freq1_line_edit.setEnabled(1)
                self._tx_freq2_line_edit.setEnabled(1)
                self._tx_freq3_line_edit.setEnabled(1)
                self._tx_freq4_line_edit.setEnabled(1)
                self._tx_freq5_line_edit.setEnabled(1)
                frec = 'self._tx_freq'+str(i+1)+'_line_edit.text()'
                efrec = float(eval(frec))
                self.lblTx1.setText(str(efrec-0.4))
                self.lblTx2.setText(str(efrec))
                self.lblTx3.setText(str(efrec+0.4))
                #print frec
                print efrec
                print threading.currentThread().getName()
                for th in threading.enumerate():
                    print th
                time.sleep(1)

manual_thread = threading.Thread(target=Exec_Manual, name='manual_thread')
manual_thread.daemon = True
manual_thread.start()

#Function B.

def Exec_Auto():  
    while True:
        for i in range(0,17):
            if self.rbtnAuto.isChecked():
                if self.rbtnMan.isChecked():
                    self.auto_sema.acquire()
                    self.manual_sema.release()
                    break
                self._tx_freq1_line_edit.setDisabled(1)
                self._tx_freq2_line_edit.setDisabled(1)
                self._tx_freq3_line_edit.setDisabled(1)
                self._tx_freq4_line_edit.setDisabled(1)
                self._tx_freq5_line_edit.setDisabled(1)
                frec0=88.5
                x=i*1.2
                efrec = float(frec0)+x
                print efrec
                print threading.currentThread().getName()#Debug
                for th in threading.enumerate():
                    print th
                self.lblTx1.setText(str(efrec-0.4))
                self.lblTx2.setText(str(efrec))
                self.lblTx3.setText(str(efrec+0.4))
                time.sleep(1)
                frec0=frec0+1.2

auto_thread = threading.Thread(target=Exec_Auto, name='auto_thread')
auto_thread.daemon = True
auto_thread.start()
```

Both auto_thread and manual_thread seem to continue executing since `threading.enumerate()` keeps showing them active (I expect one them to dissapear when the other function's radio button is checked and re start when their own radio button is checked again):

```
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 140030203459328)>
<Thread(manual_thread, started daemon 140029502768896)>
<Thread(auto_thread, started daemon 140029154293504)>
```

In the answer given by Jay [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072608/python-is-it-possible-to-stop-or-pause-a-thread), I can see that he is creating classes that inherite from `thread` and putting the functions inside those classes. ¿may that be what needs to be done to obtain the behavior I'm expecting? ¿can you provide some ideas on how to get my code to work as I expect? as always, thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ron

Comment: sorry for bad question, I read it after I wrote the whole description and saw that it may not represent what I am actually asking. hope I can explain myself though.

Comment: `threading.enumerate` will show them both alive because they are alive even if they happen to be waiting on the semaphore.

Comment: I assume `rbtnAuto` and `rbtnMan` are part of the same radio button group and both can't be set at the same time? Would it be fair to say that the state is manual if `rbtnAuto` is not checked?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @tdelaney  Yeah, when one radio button is checked, the other can't be.

Comment: As for the resource usage... look at `Exec_Manual` for instance. If `if self.rbtnMan.isChecked():` is true, you do some work and then sleep 1 second. But if its false, you immediately rerun the loop and check again. You are pounding the heck out of the system.

Comment: If you want multiple threads, you could use a `threading.Lock`. The trick is to grab the lock, then check whether you are supposed to run, run with the lock still held and release it before trying again. Since one or the other functions is always running, reacquiring the lock will naturally add a delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that trying to synchronize threads is more trouble than its worth. You need to consider timing windows such as the GUI changing state between when the two threads happen to check them. It would be easier to take the logic out of the functions and have a higher level function call one or the other on each loop. That function can tell the worker functions whether there is a state change requiring changes to the gui.

```
def Exec_Manual(state_changed):
    if state_changed:
        self._tx_freq1_line_edit.setEnabled(1)
        self._tx_freq2_line_edit.setEnabled(1)
        self._tx_freq3_line_edit.setEnabled(1)
        self._tx_freq4_line_edit.setEnabled(1)
        self._tx_freq5_line_edit.setEnabled(1)
    frec = 'self._tx_freq'+str(i+1)+'_line_edit.text()'
    efrec = float(eval(frec))
    self.lblTx1.setText(str(efrec-0.4))
    self.lblTx2.setText(str(efrec))
    self.lblTx3.setText(str(efrec+0.4))
    time.sleep(1)

def Exec_Auto(state_changed):  
    if state_changed:
        self._tx_freq1_line_edit.setDisabled(1)
        self._tx_freq2_line_edit.setDisabled(1)
        self._tx_freq3_line_edit.setDisabled(1)
        self._tx_freq4_line_edit.setDisabled(1)
        self._tx_freq5_line_edit.setDisabled(1)
    frec0=88.5
    x=i*1.2
    efrec = float(frec0)+x
    self.lblTx1.setText(str(efrec-0.4))
    self.lblTx2.setText(str(efrec))
    self.lblTx3.setText(str(efrec+0.4))
    time.sleep(1)

def the_decider():
    state = self.rbtnAuto.isChecked()
    while True:
        new_state = self.rbtnAuto.isChecked()
        if new_state:
            Exec_Auto(state == new_state)
        else:
            Exec_Manual(state == new_state)
        state = new_state

auto_thread = threading.Thread(target=the_decider, name='the_decider')
auto_thread.start()
```

Comment: thank you @tdelaney, im going to try this. If it may help,another problem is that when the program starts, it shows in the resources monitor an usage of least than 50% of CPU but when I click the other radio button, the CPU usage reaches 100% (the code is still running and GUI doesn't freeze)

Comment: i tried your code and it kinda worked as i expected (with about less than 50% CPU usage) but it doesn't change the values in the labels (e.g. in the Exec_Auto function, it should be presenting each frequency of the FM spectre in groups of 3) which I obtained by using the `for` loops that you removed. Is there any reason for what you removed the for loops?

Comment: I didn't pay much attention to that inner for because it didn't seem to matter for the question at hand... TL;DR I suppose! Anyway, you can stick that back.

Comment: I just added the for loops and it freakin worked! man, and just with about 30% CPU usage. I wish I could buy you a beer. thank you, really.

Comment: LOL... I'll be at the Cotton Bottom tomorrow night.

Comment: I said I wish I could because we are probably thousands of kilometers away from each other! greetings from the center of the world.