# request.get in Python3 hangs the terminal without allowing Ctrl-C

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying the following code piece in Python3 that hangs in terminal:

```
requests.get('http://www.ppsfs.com/en/aboutus/company')
```

I cannot even interrupt the code with Ctrl+C, and have to kill the terminal window. Trying to go to the website in the browser creates a similar response - the website loads indefinitely.

How can I handle this problem, to skip such websites?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If the same thing happens in a browser then this is a site specific issue.

To skip these types of sites when iterating over a list of urls, you'll need asynchronous processes. If you don't want to delve into multi-threading, then you can use `Scrapy` [where requests are scheduled and processed asynchronously](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html#what-just-happened)

Otherwise, the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19072608/python-is-it-possible-to-stop-or-pause-a-thread) might be a useful starting point. You'll need to modify the sempahore logic *(I think - I've not delved into multi-threading much!)*.

Comment: This is a part of the scrapy call. It is possible I didn't code it well, but this is a line from the crawler scrapy calls.

Comment: Have you tried reducing the `DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT`? https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/broad-crawls.html#reduce-download-timeout

Comment: Nope. Could it be that setting it could change from infinite wait to a finite one?

Comment: Should be. Make sure you set a reasonable figure (1 second too low, 200 seconds is too high). 10-20 should be good.

Comment: But why would requests wait for timeout instead obeying KeyboardInterrupt? Sounds like a bug.